# Which parts of a built NextJS app should I protect?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, static, next.js

I'm running a NextJS app from an Express server and I have authentication set up. The Express server will forward most requests to the NextJS app with some preprocessing. In the NextJS app, there are the explicit routes and api routes that I set up myself in the `/pages` directory of the source code, but there are also a lot of assets being requested from paths starting with `/_next/`.

When running an authenticated service, it is clear that you normally don't have to protect **ALL** of your assets. For example `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico` belong to the category of assets that do not need authentication and the same goes for many static assets.

My question is, which ones of NextJS's own routes should I protect? It seems that `/_next/static/*` mostly contain static source files that do not need any custom input data and that `/_next/data/*` contains personalized information that should be protected, thus it seems reasonable to protect the latter but not the former.

Are there other routes that NextJS serves from a built app (other than routes to assets in the `/public` folder and routes in the `pages` directory) that I should know about and is it reasonable to only protect `/_next/data/*` or should I protect all of `/_next/*`?